# Wordpress restrict categories plugin with DWQA plugin

Tags: wordpress

My environment:
using DWQA plugin and customized restrict categories plugin to work with DWQA plugin

Problem:
I have customized "restrict categories" plugin to work for DWQA instead of WP posts.
Now the problem is when I logged in as user with privileges set to category2 from restrict categories, it's not able to show anything for me.

To set category filter restrict categories is using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'posts_query' ) );

    public function posts_query( $query ){          
        if ( $this->cat_list !== '' ) {
            // Build an array for the categories
            $cat_list_array = explode( ',', $this->cat_list );    

            // Make sure the posts are removed by default or if filter category is ran
            if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['cat'] ) )      
                $query->set( 'category__in', $cat_list_array );
            elseif( isset( $_REQUEST['cat'] ) && $_REQUEST['cat'] == '0' )
                $query->set( 'category__in', $cat_list_array );
        }    

        return $query;  
    }
```

If I use category__not_in in place of category__in then all the posts are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by changing code as below

```
public function posts_query( $query ){          

        // Build an array for the categories
        $cat_list_array = explode( ',', $this->cat_list );   


   $taxquery = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'dwqa-question_category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $cat_list_array,
        'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
    )
);

$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
```

Comment: Is there an option to make from your function an  [shortcode](https://wordpress.com/support/shortcodes/)  with the `add_shortcode` from php?